# Getting ReferenceError: options is not defined when trying to use nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

```
Reference Error: options is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Dance website\app.js:6:33)
    at Module. compile (node: internal/modules/c j s/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node: internal/modules/c j s/loader:1159:10)      
    at Module. load (node: internal/modules/c j s/loader:981:32)
    at Function. Module. load (node: internal/modules/c j s/loader:822:12)
    at Function. execute User Entry Point [as run Main] (node: internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node: internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[ node mon ] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: What's your node.js version? And can you show your `package.json`, and the command you are executing to call nodemon?

Comment: Please show us how you are invoking `nodemon` as well as the contents of `app.js`.

Comment: Are you saying that you're not getting that error when not using `nodemon`? How are you invoking it then, and what is `options`?

Comment: Line: 6 in your code